# Is there a version of DataNitro for Excel that uses Python 3.5?

Tags: excel, datanitro

Is there a version of DataNitro for Excel that uses Python 3.5? I noticed the trial version uses (and installs) Python version 2.7.9.  I've been using Python 3.5 for all of my new Python projects and I'm not really too keen on having yet another version of Python on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataNitro works with Python 3.5 out of the box. To use it, skip the 2.7.9 installation (uncheck the box in the first screen of DataNitro's installer). Once DN is installed, go to Settings in the DN ribbon toolbar, uncheck "use default Python", and put in your Python 3.5 directory. After restarting Excel everything should work.